# Sequelize returning old data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, express, vue.js, axios, sequelize.js

**Problem:** what I'm *sometimes* seeing is that very old data is being returned from my various databases when I do `SELECT` operations (`findAll`).

I have a VueJS app in which I'm using AxiosJS to call my backend ExpressJS app which uses Sequelize to connect to several (4) SQL Server databases. I'm also using the VueJS Developer Tools so I can see the variables and Vuex store change in real time on the frontend. I'm also using console.log on the backend so I can see some things there too.

In searching for solutions, I have found that:

1. I'm not using transactions; all of my queries are single queries that return results to the application, so I don't (shouldn't) have issues with commit timing; i.e. I UPDATE or ADD a row and only after it returns a result do I then make a `SELECT`
2. Sequelize keeps connections open, and so old connections show as "Sleeping" in the DB; I see these do get reused over time
3. I'm using the default isolation level in SQL Server which is **READ COMMITTED** and which should return committed data; since I'm waiting for the first query to return a result before launching the second query, shouldn't it be committed and ready to get me the latest values?
4. I see that SQL Server CAN store old copies of rows, sometimes making SNAPSHOTS, but I think they require higher isolation levels - but I'm not sure about that; maybe it IS keeping old versions?
5. I've been unsuccessful in figuring out how to close and reopen Sequelize connections. I'd like to close things at logout and reconnect there too since the app is still running in the tab (if this will solve my old data problem), thereby allowing someone to relogin and open all of the DB connections to be available again. I can't figure it out based on the available docs.
6. I think Sequelize is using old connections and somehow it is that which is causing SELECT results to be stale - this is even more likely if SQL Server is keeping old versions of rows
7. For some reason, if I logout and do a hard refresh of my app (<kbd>CTRL+F5</kbd>), all data is fresh; I don't understand why this would be at all. What could the browser be holding on to? Note that the console logs on the server app are always consistent with whatever the frontend shows. In other words, if the backend console log is stale, the frontend is stale; if backend is fresh, frontend is too.
8. I am unable to duplicate the getting of stale data using SSMS or Postman

Question: So what are the possible ways I can be getting stale data when I'm using Axios on the frontend and Sequelize on the backend?

Comment: *I'm using the default isolation level in SQL Server which should get me the latest data even if it is dirty* - actually - **NO** - the default isolation level is **READ COMMITTED** which returns **only** data that has in fact been committed - not-yet-committed data ("dirty data") from ongoing transactions is **not** returned in this case

Comment: @marc_s, you're right, I misspoke or got my wires crossed. So in your opinion, could a single query followed by another single query (launched after the first one completes and returns a reponse) possibly still not show the latest value? Once the first one completes and returns, isn't that committed?

Comment: If you're not using explicit transactions - then yes, each statement should "auto-commit" once it's completed ...

Comment: Are you sure you don't get 304 instead of 200 in these requests with old data?

Comment: @marc_s, yes, I'm not using explicit transactions.
Anatoly, I'm pretty sure it's returning 200. I know I check for that in most of my .then() sections. I'll double check.

Comment: @AnatolyI checked the front end and I'm checking to make sure I get 200, otherwise I popup an error message, which I don't get when I get the old data. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: any caching you are using with axios?  I am wondering for this: "it works fine on postman and not in axios..."  I would look more into axios side.

Comment: @Emma I didn't know axios has caching. I'll look.

Comment: You could also post some snippets from backend and frontend and it would show more detail.